# Trying to create tableless control with dynamic content

Tags: css, css-tables

I am pulling some content from a webservice that creates select lists with a label as a form of title. Rules are that the select lists must line up and stack on top of each other, and take up the rest of the screen real estate that the label does not take up.

I can do this by creating them with tables, but am looking for a more pure CSS route if possible.

tried using a combination of divs with `display: table`, `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell` but I couldn't get the stacking effect to work properly.

this is the effect I am looking for:

```css
.horizontalFill {
    width: 100%;                
}

.noWrap {
    white-space: nowrap;        
}
```

```html
<table class="horizontalFill">
    <tr>
        <td class="noWrap">
            <label>some dynamic text</label>
        </td>
        
        <td class="horizontalFill">
            <select class="horizontalFill">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>        
    
    <tr>
        <td class="noWrap">
            <label>
                other dynamic text here
            </label>
        </td>
        
        <td class="horizontalFill">
           <select class="horizontalFill"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to this:

```css
label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

label .label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

label .input {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 160px;
}

label select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label class="row">
    <span class="label">Label name one</span>
    <span class="input">
        <select>
            <option>Select item</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</label>

<label class="row">
    <span class="label">Label name two</span>
    <span class="input">
        <select>
            <option>Select item</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</label>

<label class="row">
    <span class="label">Label name three</span>
    <span class="input">
        <select>
            <option>Select item</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</label>
```

It involves the label column being set to a static width, though, so it may not work out for you if you need that column to stretch or shrink.  The label text will wrap to the next line without any issue, though.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately the goal is to have the first column stretch and shrink. Tired of fighting with it in CSS, especially when i have a working solution with tables (even though not ideal) and other tasks need to be accomplished. :)